# M2Crypto import fails on Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, python-2.7, openssl, osx-yosemite, m2crypto

I have tried all possible methods to install M2Crypto on Mac OS X Yosemite.

The following link was referred to build openssl first and then swig followed by M2Crypto: http://jonatkinson.co.uk/2008/10/09/installing-m2crypto-osx/

The following link was used to change `setup.py` for M2Crypto to create static links for `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a`, but this did not work either: 
https://github.com/accessgrid/accessgrid/blame/master/packaging/mac/setup.py.m2crypto-0.17.patch

```
import M2Crypto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/M2Crypto/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/.python-eggs/M2Crypto-0.22.3-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg-tmp/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so, 2): Symbol not found: _X509_free
  Referenced from: /Users/user/.python-eggs/M2Crypto-0.22.3-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg-tmp/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user/.python-eggs/M2Crypto-0.22.3-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg-tmp/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the very same problem when trying to install saltstack. fixed it by using easy_install.

```
easy_install M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
```

M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg file downloaded from [M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto#Downloads)

also this post: http://jonatkinson.co.uk/2008/10/09/installing-m2crypto-osx/ may help

Comment: Worked for me on version 10.10.1 (14B25)